# vector<float> write to a file

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to write a type vector < float > to a file, in OpenCV.
Part of my code is:

```
vector<float> descriptorsValues;
vector<Point> locations;
d.compute(img, descriptorsValues, Size(0,0), Size(0,0), locations);
```

I want to write descriptosValues to a file. I have tried operator overloading but I'm not sure how to call the function.

```
// Writing descriptorsValues to a file
fstream data_file;
data_file.open("hog_descriptors.bin", ios::out | ios::in | ios::binary);
fstream& operator << (fstream& o, const Point& e)
{
 return o << e.descriptorsValues;
}

vector<Point>::iterator pos;
for (pos = descriptorsValues.begin(); pos != descriptorsValues.end(); ++pos)
data_file << *pos << endl;
data_file.close();
```

Comment: You've got to decide what file format to use. Wagner Patriota's solution just does a memory dump of the floats, which is OK if you're going to be reading them in later from the same program,  but could be dubious if you intend to read them via a different executable that might use a different format for its floats, or if you intend to send them to another PC, and so on.

Comment: It is crashing? Does it write? Please, bemore specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is gonna work:

```
ofstream data_file;      // pay attention here! ofstream
data_file.open("hog_descriptors.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);

size_t size = descriptorsValues.size();

for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    data_file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&descriptorsValues[i]), sizeof(float));
}

data_file.close();
```

Or, like Mike suggested, much better:

```
ofstream data_file;      // pay attention here! ofstream
data_file.open("hog_descriptors.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
data_file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&descriptorsValues[0]), descriptorsValues.size()*sizeof(float)); 
data_file.close();
```

In order to read it back, you need to know the number of items you have on your vector in the file...

```
ifstream data_file;      // NOW it's ifstream
data_file.open("hog_descriptors.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);
descriptorsValues.resize(NUMBER_OF_ITEMS);
data_file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&descriptorsValues[0]), NUMBER_OF_ITEMS*sizeof(float));
data_file.close();
```

This one above also works because the data in vector is guaranteed to be aligned in sequence, so if you get the pointer of the first items, calculating the size of the buffer with `descriptorsValues.size() * sizeof(float)` is gonna be a little faster!

Comment: why the reinterpret_cast<char*> ? care to explain ?

Comment: If you're going to do that you may as well replace the loop with a single block write of size `descriptorsValues.size() * sizeof descriptorsValues[0]`

Comment: because the signature of the method is `ofstream::write(char*,size_t)` and &descriptorsValues[i] is a `float*`, so you have to cast it

Comment: @Matt soluction is much better, once the vector is always aligned!

Answer (score 4):

I read in your post that you are using OpenCV.
There is in OpenCV a serialization library (in opencv core), see [this page](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/file_input_output_with_xml_yml/file_input_output_with_xml_yml.html).

So you can try something like this :

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace cv;
int main(int _argc, const char ** _argv)
{
    std::vector<int> toto;
    toto.push_back(1);
    toto.push_back(2);
    string filename = "I.xml";
    FileStorage fs(filename, FileStorage::WRITE);        
    fs << "toto" << toto;
    fs.release();
}
```

Read carefully the page about serialization in OpenCV, there is a lot of very interesting things

If you want to read the content of your file you can proceed with this code :

```
std::vector<int> totoRead;
FileStorage fsRead(filename, FileStorage::READ);
fsRead["toto"] >> totoRead;
fsRead.release();

std::cout << totoRead[0] << "," << totoRead[1] << std::endl;
```

As you can see it's quite easy.
All the structure presents in OpenCV (cv::Mat etc...) are serializable with this mechanism

Comment: This is a fantastic example.